# Generador barcode128, html

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día chicxs, debido a restricciones mediante firewall en la empresa donde trabajo no podemos utilizar un generador externo y los permisos de instalación de fuentes ni hablemos. Lo que estoy intentando es mediante un html y el JavaScript pero al ejecutar no muestra, a diferencia cuando está enlazado a la página externa.

```js
    function generarCodigo() {
      // Obtener el valor del input de texto
      var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;

      // Generar el código de barras utilizando JsBarcode
      JsBarcode("#barcode", codigo, {
        format: "CODE128",
        displayValue: true
      });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Formulario con código de barras 128 generado por JavaScript</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsbarcode/3.11.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Formulario con código de barras 128 generado por JavaScript</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="codigo">Código de barras:</label>
    <input type="text" id="codigo" name="codigo">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="generarCodigo()">Generar código de barras</button>
    <br><br>
    <canvas id="barcode"></canvas>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

En el apartado del javascript `src="JsBarcode.all.min.js"` , lo tengo enlazado al archivo js guardado pero no ejecuta.

Comment: El ejemplo que publicas funciona bien. ¿Estás seguro/a que estás enlazando la ubicación correcta en la etiqueta `script`? ¿Te has asegurado que el navegador carga ese script?

Comment: Hola @jachguate, tengo el archivo js en la misma carpeta del html

Comment: He visto la modificación del usuario @Luis de la function generarcodigo () ¿Cómo se debe integrar en el html?

Comment: Borrá tu _no-respuesta_, ya que en realidad es un comentario. Lo que hizo el usuario Luis fue convertir tu código a _snippet_, para poder ejecutar tal código en la pregunta misma. En ese snippet, el resultado sí se muestra, aparte probablemente vos mismo/a respondiste a tu propia pregunta: _debido a restricciones mediante firewall_... Fijate si en la consola del navegador te marca algún error.

Comment: No entiendo algo, si estas programando algo significa que eres de IT, si eres de IT debes tener acceso al Firewall o al menos privilegios... Algo no me cuadra pues por más cerrada que este una empresa, si se necesita algo para desempeñar una labor te la deben permitir...

Comment: @Ochoa, creo que te falta experiencia en el mundo corporativo al afirmar que alguien de IT _debe_ tener acceso al firewall, pues son los que menos _deben_ tenerlo, y si bien es cierto que si necesitas algo para desempeñar una labor debieran permitirlo, eso regularmente no es así si ese algo está _fuera_ de la política general o si implica un esfuerzo y falta conocimiento o a criterio del jefe no vale el costo.

Comment: Pueda ser porque en todas las empresas donde he trabajado (incluyendo gobierno) nosotros hemos manejado el FW. Pero bueno, era solo una opinión personal...

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios, por el snippet no tenía idea. @OCHOA no soy programador de la empresa, es una mera herramienta que necesitamos y no se ejecuta ni en mis dispositivos personales por lo que no es restricción de la organización.